# Binary search in Java

Tags: java

I have started learning Java recently and was looking into some easy algorithms. I found the Binary Search Algorithm [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)

I am trying to get better at writing good code for my solutions. I have used MergeSort for sorting the unsorted array first.Please give me your suggestions.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class binarysearch {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            int size = keyboard.nextInt();
            int[] array = new int[size];
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                array[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
            }
            // sort the array using mergesort
            mergeSort (array);
            System.out.println("Enter the element to search");
            int searchkey = keyboard.nextInt();
            // call the function to do the binary search
            binarySearch (array, searchkey);

        }

        private static void binarySearch(int[] array, int searchkey) {

            int low = 0; // lowest index
            int high = array.length - 1; // highest index
            int guess = (low + high) / 2;

            while (low <= high) {
                if (array[guess] == searchkey) {
                    System.out.println("The element " + searchkey
                            + " is found at the index " + guess);
                    break;
                } else if (array[guess] < searchkey) {
                    low = guess + 1;
                } else
                    high = guess - 1;
                guess = (low + high) / 2;

            }
            if (low > high) {
                System.out.println("The element " + searchkey + " is not found");
            }

        }

        private static int[] mergeSort(int[] a) {

            if (a.length <= 1) {
                return a;
            }

            // split the array into two halves

            int[] first = new int[a.length / 2];
            int[] second = new int[a.length - first.length];

            System.arraycopy(a, 0, first, 0, first.length);
            System.arraycopy(a, first.length, second, 0, second.length);

            mergeSort (first);
            mergeSort (second);

            merge (first, second, a);

            return a;

        }

        private static void merge(int[] first, int[] second, int[] a) {
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;
            int k = 0;

            while (i < first.length && j < second.length) {
                if (first[i] <= second[j]) {
                    a[k] = first[i];        
                    i++;
                    k++;
                } else {
                    a[k] = second[j];       
                    j++;
                    k++;
                }

            }

            while (i < first.length) {
                a[k++] = first[i++];
            }
            while (j < second.length) {
                a[k++] = second[j++];
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll only be reviewing the binary search portion of the code since that's what it seems like you're asking for.

**Separation of Concerns**

You should separate I/O from processing and let the user control what kind of I/O they'd like to have. So I would remove the output statements from your `binarySearch` function and find a better way to indicate the element was not found. The solution I'll go with is that we'll return the index of the element if it is found and -1 otherwise (since -1 is never a valid array index).

**Better Naming**

You call the middle element `guess` even though it is not a `guess`. Someone unfamiliar with binary search would read this code and assume that you *guessed the element was in the middle*. This is not true so I would rename that variable to `pivot` or `middle`. Moreover, you can move the calculation of it to be inside the while loop.

**Miscellaneous**

1. Use consistent bracing style (e.g. always use them. They never hurt).
2. The `if` statement at the end of the binary search is unnecessary since when we exit the `while` loop, we know that `low > high`.
3. Since `middle` won't be changing in one `while` loop cycle, we can mark it `final`.

Here is a possible implementation taking into account all of the above.

```
    private static int binarySearch(int[] array, int searchkey) {

        int low = 0; // lowest index
        int high = array.length - 1; // highest index

        while (low <= high) {
            final int middle = low + (high - low) / 2;
            if (array[middle] == searchkey) {
                return middle;
            } else if (array[middle] < searchkey) {
                low = middle + 1;
            } else {
                high = middle - 1;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```